# indexing mysql records with elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to get resultset from mysql db and then converting to json and then indexing using elastic search api.

Did google and found that using logstash I can directly index the data to elastic search,searched a lot but dint find any sample code how to do this via java code.

I am not sure which will be the best way to go for (indexing using logstash or convert resultset into json and then do indexing via elasticsearch).

Any sample code/link will be highly helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to do it using `logstash` you might have to use the [jdbc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html) input plugin, where you may able to draw data from your `MySQL` database and index it into your `elasticsearch` instance.

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://yourhost:3306/yourdb" 
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "root"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "/pathtojar/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        schedule => "* * * * *" <-- if you need the query to be running continuously at a time span 
        statement => "SELECT * FROM yourtable" <-- change the query to your need        
        jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
        jdbc_page_size => "50000"
    }
}
```

The above is just a sample, so that you could reproduce it to your need. I'm not pretty sure of which way it's better, whether to converting it to `json` or plainly index it using `logstash`. You might want to have a look at this [thread](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-way-to-setup-MySQL-to-Elasticsearch-replication). Hope it helps!

Comment: I am willing to use logstash,but not sure how to use above conf file integration with my java code...

Comment: worked finally using ans from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504385/run-logstash-in-java-program