# How to execute logstash commands from a java program?

Tags: java, mongodb, parsing, command-line, logstash

I'm using logstash to extract data from log files. I wish to call logstash from a java program. How can I perform such task?

Comment: What does this have to do with MongoDB? And also, what do you want to achieve? There are HTTP APIs available for Logstash: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Logstash in Java Program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504385/run-logstash-in-java-program)

Comment: Wow. great. I'm storing the logstash output data directly in a mongoDB database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Logstash in Java Program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504385/run-logstash-in-java-program)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked.

```
        ProcessBuilder b1 = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"C:\\elk\\logstash-5.1.2\\bin\" && logstash -f first-pipeline.conf --config.reload.automatic");
        b1.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p1 = b1.start();
        BufferedReader r1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));
        String line1;
        while (true) {
            line1 = r1.readLine();
            if (line1 == null) { break; }
            System.out.println(line1);
        }
```